# Is it more performant to write named functions in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am developing an app in node js. I was using anonymous functions for callback purpose. Then I referred [callbackhell.com](http://callbackhell.com/) site where I found writing named function is best way for coding.

But when I started writing code in named function format, my lines of code increased, my functions count increased. Is it better to write named function for every single callback.

Performance wise which is better?

Comment: Depends on the context; if it's a short one liner callback don't use named functions, for large callbacks a named function is better. This also is highly influenced by your coding style.

Comment: Thanks @Zeeker for quick response. I will prefer suggestion for short one liner callback

Comment: but is there any performance difference between anonymous function and writing named functions.

Comment: No there is no performance difference.

Comment: @Abhijeet: if you don't need closure and can declare your function once outside of where it is used, not using a function expression can have a performance difference.

Comment: If your function counter increases by naming functions, your counter is broken. (And of course, it's not a very meaningful metric anyway)

Comment: Yeah @Bergi, I need to think about it.

Comment: I am just curious about performance difference between named and anonymous functions. but thanks this made me more curious to study on this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you may add more lines to your code, **function declaration** *is* the fastest. This particularly applies to instances where you are invoking the same function multiple times. Ex. collection lookups, array iteration, etc...

Using [Benchmark.js](http://benchmarkjs.com/), you can quickly see the difference.

```
☃ seth:~/Node/function-performance$ node test.js
Anonymous x 121 ops/sec ±8.31% (64 runs sampled)
Function Expression x 137 ops/sec ±5.25% (72 runs sampled)
Function Declaration x 165 ops/sec ±0.84% (86 runs sampled)
Fastest is Function Declaration
```

This is using the following code to test:

```
"use strict";

var Benchmark = require('benchmark')
var suite = new Benchmark.Suite

var stuff = [1,2,3,4,5,6,9,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15];

var myEventHandler = function() {
  // do something
};

function myEventHandler2() {
  // do something
};

suite.add('Anonymous', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    stuff.forEach(function() {
      // do something
    });
  }
})
.add('Function Expression', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    stuff.forEach(myEventHandler);
  }
})
.add('Function Declaration', function() {
  for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i) {
    stuff.forEach(myEventHandler2);
  }
})
.on('cycle', function(e) {
  console.log(String(e.target))
})
.on('complete', function() {
  console.log('Fastest is ' + this.filter('fastest').pluck('name'))
})
.run({ 'async': true });
```

The same also goes for the [browser](http://jsperf.com/named-or-anonymous-functions/12).

To support Zeeker's comment - In the event you're not running the function more than once in a given instance, you can usually get away with anonymous functions, however it can clean up your invocations when using function declarations.

Comment: Why is your test code *creating* an anonymous function, but *invoking* the declaration and the global expression?

Comment: You really should use strict mode, it would have thrown on the undeclared `myEventHandler` variable.

Comment: Good point. I ported this from a browser implementation and didn't update the example. I updated the example to reflect an instance where a function accepts a callback. Also, since the example wouldn't have variable collision, global vars weren't an issue. I did update it however.

Comment: Thank you! The problem with the global variable was not the possible collision, but that they are much slower to access (compare to the local declaration)

Comment: Worth pointing out that aside from performance differences, named functions are more readable in stack traces.